# How to change text color of disabled button with material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have this code

```
   <Button variant="text" disabled sx={{
        border: '1px solid black',
          '&:disabled': {
            color: 'green'
          }
       }}
    >
        <Typography sx={{
           color: 'red',
           '&:disabled': {
              color: 'green'
           }
        }}>Some text</Typography>
   </Button>
```

As you see I try to make disabled button text color "green", but none of this options (in button and in text css) works. How to do it?

p.s. Limitation - I can't use *.css files in this project.

Comment: try using !important, does it work ? maybe it's overriden by another class

Comment: It doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working but at Typography you assign the color attribute is green when Typography is disabled, not the button so the color green wont be apply!
You may want to remove Typography instead.

```
<Button variant="text" disabled sx={{
      border: '1px solid black',
        '&:disabled': {
          color: 'green'
        }
     }}
  >
      Some text
 </Button>
```